# Problems with command substitution (variable is empty)

Tags: linux, unix, lsf, command-substitution

Having some trouble with command substitution in a shell script. I've used this script before on another system, so not sure what's going on here. Seems like no matter how I enclose the commands to set the variable, I'm getting an empty variable. I've tried many different ways to enclose them (`$()`, backticks, quotes). If it helps, I'm trying to submit an array job.

```
#!/bin/bash
#BSUB -q shared
#BSUB -W 23:55
#BSUB -M 51200
#BSUB -J windowCovR1
#BSUB -R "span[hosts=1]"

mem=$LSB_JOBINDEX
sample=`head -n "$mem" bednames.txt | tail -1 | awk '{print $2}'`
eval ${sample}
echo ${sample}
```

`$mem` is being set properly, it's something with the `sample` line. The `echo` command prints an empty line.

Comment: [I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Comment: I don't think that really addresses this problem...this has worked before for me (on a different system), so not sure what is going on now.

Comment: Perhaps `bednames.txt` is empty? A better way to get line `N` from the file might be `sample=$(awk -vlineno=${mem} 'NR == lineno { print $2 }' bednames.txt)`...

Comment: It's not empty...I ended up doing this with a loop which wasn't ideal. Will update if I solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach of "try[ing] backticks" does not seem to be correct.

If the result of the substitution is empty, it's because that's the variable's value. Have you tried debugging the command whose output sets that variable via the terminal?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using `$LSB_JOBINDEX`, you probably want an array job.  The job name should include the start and end parameters of the array.  e.g.,

```
#BSUB -J windowCovR1[1-100]
```

This assume that there are 100 command lines in the file `bednames.txt`. Without the array bounds, `$LSB_JOBINDEX` will always be zero.  `head -n 0` will give empty string.

I tried this simple example and it works ok for me.

```
 [mclosson@host ~]$ cat tmp.sh
 #!/bin/bash
 #BSUB -q normal
 #BSUB -W 23:55
 #BSUB -M 10
 #BSUB -J windowCovR1[1-2]
 #BSUB -R "span[hosts=1]"

 mem=$LSB_JOBINDEX
 echo "$$ mem $mem" >> /tmp/LOG
 sample=`head -n "$mem" bednames.txt | tail -1 | awk '{print $2}'`
 echo "$$ ${sample}" >> /tmp/LOG

 [mclosson@host ~]$ cat bednames.txt
 line11 line12
 line21 line22

 [mclosson@host ~]$ bsub < tmp.sh
 Job <805> is submitted to queue <normal>.

 [mclosson@host ~]$ cat /tmp/LOG
 7979 mem 1
 7979 line12
 7991 mem 2
 7991 line22
```

Another small point.  If this isn't a parallel job then `-R "span[hosts=1]"` isn't needed.

Answer (score -1):

Your command to assign the value of sample is correct. Working for me as well on command line.
However, you are using the same in shell script.
So for that try using below :-

sample=`head -n "$mem" bednames.txt | tail -1 | awk '{print \$2}'`

\ before $2.
It might happen that when you are using without \ , the script checks for second command line argument.

Comment: Within single quotes, there is no need to escape the `$`, and doing so will in fact cause `awk` to complain about a syntax error.